# I am Getting an Exception " java.util.NoSuchElementException at Optional.java" while running my suite , not sure how to overcome this exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am getting an exception " **java.util.NoSuchElementException at Optional.java**" while running my gradle tests. I intent is to run feature files in parallel hence using the **Courgette** plugin.

```
**Jdk version used : 1.8**
```

**Below is my Code runner class**
**=============================**

```
  package suites.testng;

import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTargetDir = "build/chrome",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; project_info=Courgette-JVM is awesome!",
        plugin = {"extentreports"},
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/features",
                glue = "steps",
                tags = {"@sanity_ui"},
                publish = true,
                plugin = {"pretty",
                        "json:build/chrome/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:build/chrome/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"
                }
        ))
public class ChromeTestSuite extends TestNGCourgette {
}


**My build.gradle file**
**=====================**

    
        plugins { 
                  id 'java'
                  id 'maven-publish' 
                  id 'java-library'  
                  id 'groovy'   
                  id 'eclipse'  
                 // id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
               }
        
        
        
        compileJava {
            sourceCompatibility = 1.8
            targetCompatibility = 1.8
        }
        
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        def cucumberVersion = '4.8.0'
        def gherkinVersion  = '5.1.0'
        def hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
        
        def testngVersion = '6.14.3'
        def cucumber4adapterVersion = '1.0.11'
        
        def Log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
        def slf4jVersion = '1.7.5'
        
        def restassuredVersion = '3.3.0'
        def jsonsimpleVersion = '1.1.1'
        
        def appiumjavaClientVersion = '7.3.0'
        
        def allurePluginVersion = '2.8.1'
        def allurecucumber4jvmVersion = '2.13.0'
        def codeborneselenideVersion = '5.3.1'
        
        def apacheJMeterVersion = '2.2'
        def jdkIntClassesVersion = '4.5'
        def azureSDKVersion = '1.36.3'
        def azureClientAuthVersion = '1.0.0-beta1'
        def azureStorageClientSDKVersion = '8.6.5'
        def azureBlobStorageVersion = '12.0.0'
        def azureCommonStorageVersion = '12.9.0-beta.2'
        def fasterXMLJacksonCoreVersion = '2.2.3'
        def fasterXMLJacksonAnnotationsVersion = '2.1.2'
        def commonsCodecVersion = '1.6'
        def commonsLoggingVersion = '1.1.3'
        def dom4jVersion = '2.1.3'
        def orgJSONVersion = '20140107'
        def orgJSONSimpleVersion = '1.1.1'
        def okioVersion = '1.13.0'
        def apachePOIVersion = '3.9'
        def unirestVersion = '1.4.7'
        def xmlBeansVersion = '2.3.0'
        
        dependencies {
            testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.13.1'
            compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '4.0.0-alpha-3'
            testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-firefox-driver', version: '3.11.0'
        
            testCompile 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan:courgette-jvm:5.8.0'
            testCompile 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan:webdriver-binary-downloader:1.2.2'
        
            //Cucumber Gherkin
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:${gherkinVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:${cucumberVersion}"
           // testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-core:${cucumberVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:${cucumberVersion}"
             compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '4.8.0'
            //Hamcrest
            testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:${hamcrestVersion}"
        
            //Cucumber Adapter Extent Reports
            //testImplementation  'com.aventstack:extentreports:4.0.9'   // Do not use this when you are using Cucumber Adapter Extent reports. Not Required when Adapter used
            testImplementation  "com.aventstack:extentreports-cucumber4-adapter:${cucumber4adapterVersion}"
        
            //Log4j Logs
            implementation "log4j:log4j:${Log4jVersion}"  //Do not change from implementation to testImplementation otherwise  PropertyConfigurator and Logger will throw errors
        
            //Rest Assured Apis
            testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${restassuredVersion}"
            testImplementation "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:${jsonsimpleVersion}"
            testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
        
            //Selenium Apis
           compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '3.141.59'
        //    implementation 'com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:1.1.4'
            implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
            compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: '2.52.0'
            //Allure Reports
            testImplementation "io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber4-jvm:${allurecucumber4jvmVersion}"
            implementation "io.qameta.allure:allure-selenide:${allurecucumber4jvmVersion}"
            implementation "com.codeborne:selenide:${codeborneselenideVersion}"
        
            //Appium
            implementation "io.appium:java-client:${appiumjavaClientVersion}"
        
            //Azure
            //Azure SDK
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure', version: azureSDKVersion
            //Azure Client Authentication
            testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-client-authentication', version: azureClientAuthVersion
            //Azure Storage Client SDK
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: azureStorageClientSDKVersion
            //Azure Blob Storage
            compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: azureBlobStorageVersion
            //Azure Common Storage
            compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-common', version: azureCommonStorageVersion
        
            //FasterXML (Jackson)
            //Jackson Core
            compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: fasterXMLJacksonCoreVersion
            //Jackson Annotations
            compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: fasterXMLJacksonAnnotationsVersion
        
            //Commons
            //Commons Codec
            compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: commonsCodecVersion
            //Commons Logging
            compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: commonsLoggingVersion
        
            //Dom4j
            compile group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: dom4jVersion
        
            //JSON
            compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: orgJSONVersion
            compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: orgJSONSimpleVersion
        
            //Okio
            compile group: 'com.squareup.okio', name: 'okio', version: okioVersion
        
            //ApachePOI
            //POI
            compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: apachePOIVersion
            //POI OOXML
            compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: apachePOIVersion
            //POI OOXML Schemas
            compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: apachePOIVersion
        
            //Unirest
            compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: unirestVersion
        
            //XMLBeans
            compile group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: xmlBeansVersion
        
            //Netty Jar is important
            compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.31.Final'
        
            //AspectJweaver
            runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.6'
        
            compile group: 'com.browserstack', name: 'browserstack-integration', version: '1.0.0'
            compile group: 'com.browserstack', name: 'browserstack-local-java', version: '0.3.0'
        
            compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.7'
        
            //SqlServer
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.1.jre8'
        
            // External Jar files
            // compile fileTree(dir: 'java_lib', include: ['*.jar'])
        
        
            testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'testng-6.14.3.jar')   //This should be last statement
        
        
        }
        
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            systemProperties = System.getProperties()
            systemProperties.remove("java.endorsed.dirs")
        }
        
        
        /* TestNG Specific Tasks
        ----------------------------------------------------
        */
        task runTest(type: Test) {
         //   dependsOn compileJava, assemble, testClasses
            useTestNG()
        
            systemProperty("browser", "chrome")
        
            include '**/lib/testng-6.14.3.jar'
            include '**/suites/testng/ChromeTestSuite.class'
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        }
        
        task runFirefoxTestsUsingTestNG(type: Test) {
            useTestNG()
        
            systemProperty("browser", "firefox")
        
            include '**/suites/testng/FirefoxTestSuite.class'
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        }



**After Running I am getting the below exception**
```

=======================================================

[image]

Comment: The clue is in the stack trace.  What's on line 135 in optional.java?  - no such element means selenium cannot find your identifier. That's what you you need to fix

Comment: Thanks RichEdwards for your reply. First of all I don`t have this Optional.java file in my entire project. Just guessing is it part of JDK 1.8

Comment: The NoSuchElement exception raised in this case is totally different than the one of Selenium. As you can see, it's part of java.util package, not org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.

The function from the Optional that is returning this exception is most probably this: 

public T get() {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No value present");
        }
        return value;
    }

I would raise this issue directly on the Courgette github page, since I believe this exception should be handled on their side.

Comment: @RichEdwards : Totally Agree with you, I have already raised an issue on Courgette github page.